# Closing dialog box and form which launched the dialog box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form in a winforms app. When I press a button, it loads a modal message box with the options yes and no.

This is fine, but when I press no, I want to close both the dialog box and the form where the button which launched the dialog box (the sender) is.

So the app structure is like this:

Main app window > press menu item to launch new form (connection setup) > press button on this form to launch message box.

Two windows are open (connection setup form and dialog box), which I both want closed.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 20):

In your yes-no modal form, just set `DialogResult` to *No* when you press the *No* button, like:

```
private void noButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No;
}
```

and the modal form will automatically close when you click *No*

Then when you open your modal form do something like this (in the connection setup form):

```
var modalForm = new YesNoForm();
if (modalForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.No)
{
    this.Close(); // close the connection setup form
}
```

**EDIT**

I thought your yes-no modal form was custom, if it's a simple MessageBox, just do:

```
var dlgResult = MessageBox.Show("Yes or no ?","?",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(dlgResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
{
    this.Close(); // close the connection setup form
}
```

as already suggested in other answers

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("dialog", "modal", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
      this.Close();
}
```

For custom modal dialogs code will be similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text != "")
        {

            if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(("Do you want to save changes to Untiteled"), "Notepad", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel))
            {

                saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".txt", FileMode.Append);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
                sw.Close();
                fs.Close();

            }
            else if (DialogResult.No == MessageBox.Show(("Do you want to save changes to Untiteled"), "Notepad", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel))
            {

                richTextBox1.Clear();

            }
            else if (DialogResult.Cancel == MessageBox.Show(("Do you want to save changes to Untiteled"), "Notepad", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel))
            {


                 ***//when i click on cancel button...the dialogbox should be close??????????????????????***
            }

        }
        else
        { 
            richTextBox1.Clear(); 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if C# has the same behavior, but in Java I modify the constructor of the message box, and pass a reference to the sender form.

```
MBox1 = New MBox(ParentForm sender);
```

Then in the message box you can do:

```
sender.close(); //or whatever
this.close();
```

The examples are more "pseudocode-like" but I hope it helps