# Close about box

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying do make a windows software. But when I added the `About` inside the `Help` button which is inside the menu stripe.

I created a new winform from the VS 2013 templates called "AboutBox", and it comes with a button `OK`. I want this button when clicked to close only this "About Box". I pasted down here only the button method, I didn't change anything at all from the code

```
private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //close aboutBox;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529550/closing-dialog-box-and-form-which-launched-the-dialog-box?rq=1

Comment: I thought it, but it doesn't. :/

Comment: Just set its DialogResult to OK from designer, no need to handle any event. BTW in case you just need to call Close()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
this.Close();
```

Or, as someone pointed out, just edit the resource in the IDE for the button and set the **DialogResult** property.:

[image: Set DialogResult property for the button]

Comment: If the form is shown via ShowDialog, you don't need the `this.Close();` line.  Changing the DialogResult to anything other than None will close the form.